# JScrollBar setValue not working when a dialog not visible

Tags: java, swing, scroll, scrollbar, jscrollpane

Here is my simple example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class SelectItem extends JDialog {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private String item;
    private ButtonGroup group;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 133, 102);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton btnSelectItem = new JButton("select item");
        btnSelectItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
                    items.add(String.valueOf(c));
                SelectItem dialog = new SelectItem(frame, items, items.get(20));

                System.out.println("Item = " + dialog.showChooseDialog());
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnSelectItem);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String showChooseDialog(){
        setVisible(true);
        return item;
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public SelectItem(JFrame parent, ArrayList<String> items, String selectedItem) {
        super(parent, null, Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
        setTitle("Select Item");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 228);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        int marginX = 6;
        int currentY = 7;
        int width = 420;
        int height = 23;
        int paddingY = 26;
        int scrollY = 0;
        group = new ButtonGroup();

        for (String str: items){
            JRadioButton rd = new JRadioButton(str);
            rd.setBounds(marginX, currentY, width, height);
            currentY = currentY + paddingY;
            panel.add(rd);
            group.add(rd);

            if (str == selectedItem){ //or str.equals()...
                group.setSelected(rd.getModel(), true);
                //scrollY = rd.getY() - height/2 - scrollPane.getHeight()/2;
                scrollY = rd.getY() + height/2 - scrollPane.getHeight()/2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("ScrollY: " + scrollY);

        Dimension size = panel.getPreferredSize();
        size.setSize(size.getWidth(), currentY);
        panel.setPreferredSize(size);
        //this.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollY);

        panel.repaint();
        panel.revalidate();
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().repaint();
        scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().revalidate();
        scrollPane.repaint();
        scrollPane.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
        this.revalidate();

        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Enumeration<AbstractButton> iter = group.getElements();

                        while (iter.hasMoreElements()){
                            AbstractButton rd = iter.nextElement();
                            if (group.isSelected(rd.getModel())){
                                item = rd.getActionCommand();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //System.out.println(group.getSelection().getActionCommand());
                        setVisible(false);
                        dispose();
                    }
                });
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        item = null;
                        setVisible(false);
                        dispose();
                    }
                });
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a list of String and then pass it to a JDialog constructor with a `default string value`, or `selectedItem` as in my code.
This dialog will display all item of the list and let the user choose one.
This is done by using JRadioButton, and the JRadioButton object with it value equals to `default value` will be selected by default.

Everything work fine. But I want to scroll the panel to that radio-button automatically when a dialog is open, that radio-button will be in middle of vertical alignment

Like this:
[image]
.

```
if (str == selectedItem){ //or str.equals()...
    group.setSelected(rd.getModel(), true);
    scrollY = rd.getY() + height/2 - scrollPane.getHeight()/2;
}
...
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollY);
```

But when the dialog isopened, it doesn't scroll to that position.

I know that something hasn't been updated because a dialog are not visible.

Try adding

```
this.setVisible(true);
```

before update the scrollbar, the dialog will be open twice, and in the second time, it display correctly as I want.

But i still don't know how to solve this problem.
Anyone can help me. Thanks.
(sorry for my bad grammar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

1. Get rid of all the repaint() and revalidate() methods. The only time you need to use those methods is when you add/remove components from a visible GUI. In that case the order is `revalidate()` (to invoke the layout manager) and then `repaint()` (to paint the components at there new size/location).
2. Get rid of null layouts. Scrolling works better when you use layout managers and each component determines it own size.

Regarding your problem the maximum value of the scrollbar is only 100 at the time you execute your code, so you can't set the value to 240. I would guess this is because you have not used the pack() method on the dialog before you make it visible. You should be able to set the value of the scrollbar after the pack().

Or, maybe a better approach is the use panel.scrollRectToVisible(....). This seems to work even if you don't pack() the dialog.

Comment: Thank for your help. I use scrollRectToVisible(...) and it works fine.

Comment: I can't implement JDialog.pack() to work                             
- `contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(434, 228));`
...
-`setValue(scrollY);`
...
`this.pack();`
`setVisible(true);`
This doesn't work. Can u give some code. Thanks